# module.js:549 throw err; Error: Cannot find module './models/TodoListModel' Nodemon shows this error on adding model file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

While  i am trying to add my model file which is ToDoListModel.js in my server.js file following error is shown:--

```
**module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^**

    **Error: Cannot find module './models/TodoListModel'**
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\todolist\server.js:28:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting
```

...

---

[image: Project Folder Structure]

**when added foenter image description herellowing code in server.js it shows error-**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
var Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');
```

**Schema is created in ToDoListModel.js**

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
       type: String,
       require: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
     },
    Created_date: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
     },
   status: {
      type: [{
          type: String,
          enum: ['pending', 'ongoing', 'completed']
       }],
    default: ['pending']
    }
 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

**Any help will be appricated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server.js file is unable to locate your TodoListModel.js file.
you should give the exact path of your model file in **server.js**,
try this it will work.

```
    var Tasks = require('./app/models/TodoListModel');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly you should be able to access the Tasks object just by doing this:

var Tasks = require('./models/TodoListModel');

Comment: yes. i wanna use ToDoListModel.js file in server.js file. but couldn't find what is the exact solution